# Does not the Bode Diagrama of the inputs of the system?

Tags: python, dynamic, controls, state-space, time-frequency

I am implementing a python code that performs with a Bode Diagram of a dynamic system. Nevertheless, according to a command available at the library of "Signal.Processing" of Scipy, the Bode diagram does not depends of the inputs of the dynamic system. Is that correct? I thought that I should consider the inputs (perturbing forces) to construct the diagram.

Here is the comand that I used:

```
w, mag, phase = signal.bode(sys)
```

where sys is the dynamic of the system on State Space Model:

```
sys=signal.StateSpace(A,B,C,D)
```

Note that the inputs (u) is not considered in "sys"

Answer (score -1):

I think, the Bode diagram only applies to the transfer function of the system, not the inputs. But I'm not a 100% sure.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer - it does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you'll be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on all posts. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173) to learn about this limit and what you should do instead. Comments posted as answers are subject to removal, or you can delete it yourself.